# Add image to an existing PDF as header

Tags: vb.net

i have to add an existing image to an existing pdf without cover the pdf content or modify it, in the top-left corner.

I was thinking to create a blank header ad put the image into.

Any one know how to make it?

There are other possibility?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add an image to pages of a PDF using [Docotic.Pdf library](http://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/).

**VB.NET Code**

```
Public Shared Sub AddImageToAllPages()
    Using pdf As New PdfDocument("input.pdf")
        Dim image As PdfImage = pdf.AddImage("image.png")

        For Each page As PdfPage In pdf.Pages
            page.Canvas.DrawImage(image, 100, 100)
        Next

        pdf.Save("out.pdf")
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok, but this will put the image over the pdf content. I need that the image WON'T COVER anything of th existing pdf

Comment: You can draw the image on background in 3 steps: 1. Create XObject with DrawOnBackground = true; 2. Draw the image on this XObject 3. Draw XObject in the top-left corner.

Here is the sample for XObject usage: https://github.com/BitMiracle/Docotic.Pdf.Samples/tree/master/Samples/XObjects%2C%20watermarks%20and%20backgrounds/Watermarks